# Calculation of Convolution Integral Over a Positive Domain in MATLAB

Tags: function, matlab, math, signal-processing, convolution

Suppose we want to compute the [convolution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution) of sine and a Gaussian functions from 0 to 10. Below you can see a code that does this using two methods. In the first method the MATLAB function conv() is used and in the second method it is calculated directly.

```
clear all
clc

x = linspace(0, 10, 101);
dx = x(2) - x(1);

a = @(x) sin(x);
b = @(x) -exp(-x.^2);

y = conv(a(x), b(x),'same') * dx;

t = linspace(-10, 10, 100); 
z = zeros(size(x));
for i = 1:length(x)
    uu = a(t).*b(x(i)-t);
    z(i) = trapz(t,uu);
end

figure(1)
hold on
plot(x, y, 'DisplayName','conv()')
plot(x, z, 'DisplayName','direct')
```

The two methods give different results as it is seen from the figure below.

[image]

However if we use conv() from -10 to 10 and after doing the calculation only keep the part of the result that corresponds to the interval 0 to 10, the two methods give the same results.

```
clear all
clc

x = linspace(0, 10, 101);
xf = linspace(-10,10,201);
dx = x(2) - x(1);
x0 = find(xf==0);

a = @(x) sin(x);
b = @(x) -exp(-x.^2);

y = conv(a(xf), b(xf),'same') * dx;
y = y(x0:end);

t = linspace(-10, 10, 100); 
z = zeros(size(x));
for i = 1:length(x)
    uu = a(t).*b(x(i)-t);
    z(i) = trapz(t,uu);
end

figure(1)
hold on
plot(x, y, 'DisplayName','conv()')
plot(x, z, 'DisplayName','direct')
```

As it is seen from the figure below the results are the same.

[image]

I have two questions:

1- Why conv() doesn't work for the positive domain and only when the negative numbers are included we get the right result?

2- Is there a way to use only the function conv() and the interval 0 to 10 and get the same result? I want to use convolution integrals in a very complicated code and the direct method is very slow so I want to use conv(). However the structure of the code is such that I can't use the negative domain as I have used in this example.

Comment: This is a bit messy. Why do you have 2 variables for the `x` axis? Shouldn't `x` and `t` be the same variable in your first script?

Comment: t is the variable that gets integrated over in the direct method. You can check the wikipedia page for convolution integral to see it more clearly. However x is the domain in which I'm trying to find convolution. In the first section I used x in both conv() and direct methods and it gave different results. In the second section I used x for the direct method and xf (which is x extended to the negative part) for conv() and after calculating the result I trim the final array using y = y(x0:end) so that I only keep the part of the result that corresponds to 0 to 10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plot the two sampled signals you’re convolving. You’ll notice that you have only half a Gaussian. When using the (-10,10) interval, you sample the full Gaussian, and hence get a correct result.

To get the right result, you need to shift the Gaussian so that it is fully sampled:

```
y = conv(a(x), b(x-5),'same') * dx;
```

If you shift the Gaussian such that its origin is in the middle sample, the output function will not seem shifted, `conv` assumes the origin is in the middle of the arrays.