# Calculating Convolution Only for a Certain Interval Using "conv()" in MATLAB

Tags: matlab, math, signals, signal-processing, convolution

Below you can see the code for convolution of two continuous functions. There is a function called `fx` which I took as the square root of a Gaussian distribution. The convolution is calculated using 2 methods. In one of them I use the built-in function `conv()` and in the other I use the definition of the convolution. In `mat_conv1` and `cont_conv1` the function `fx` is convolved with itself using the built-in and explicit calculation methods respectively. In `mat_conv2` and `cont_conv2` the two functions mat_conv1 and cont_conv1 are convolved with themselves using their respective methods. You can see the code below.

```
clear all
clc

a = 0;
b = 1;
c1 = 0.1;
c2 = 0.2;
d1 = 0.3;
d2 = 0.4;
ymin = -2;
ymax = 2;
ynum = 400;
ylist = linspace(ymin,ymax,ynum);

conv_1 = mat_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);
conv_2 = cont_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);

hold on
plot(ylist,conv_1,'DisplayName','conv()');
plot(ylist,conv_2','DisplayName','continuous');
legend('-DynamicLegend');

function res = fx(x,a,b)
res = sqrt(normpdf(x,a,b));
end

function res = mat_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

gx_1 = fx(y/c1,a,b);
gx_2 = fx(y/c2,a,b);

res = (1/(c1*c2))*conv(gx_1,gx_2,'same')*dy;
end

function res = mat_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

hx_1 = mat_conv1(y/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
hx_2 = mat_conv1(y/d2,c1,c2,a,b);

res = (1/(d1*d2))*conv(hx_1,hx_2,'same')*dy;
end


function res = cont_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = -2:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    gx_1 = fx(xx/c1,a,b);
    gx_2 = fx((y(i)-xx)/c2,a,b);
    yy = gx_1.*gx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(c1*c2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end

function res = cont_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = -2:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    hx_1 = cont_conv1(xx/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
    hx_2 = cont_conv1((y(i)-xx)/d2,c1,c2,a,b);
    yy = hx_1.*hx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(d1*d2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end
```

As you can see from the figure below the results match pretty neatly.

[image]

Now I only want to consider the positive domain. In other words, I want to take the convolution in the interval [0,2]. So I change `ymin` to zero and inside the functions `cont_conv1` and `cont_conv2` I start the vector `xx` from zero. The code is:

```
clear all
clc

a = 0;
b = 1;
c1 = 0.1;
c2 = 0.2;
d1 = 0.3;
d2 = 0.4;
ymin = 0;
ymax = 2;
ynum = 400;
ylist = linspace(ymin,ymax,ynum);

conv_1 = mat_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);
conv_2 = cont_conv2(ylist,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b);

hold on
plot(ylist,conv_1,'DisplayName','conv()');
plot(ylist,conv_2','DisplayName','continuous');
legend('-DynamicLegend');

function res = fx(x,a,b)
res = sqrt(normpdf(x,a,b));
end

function res = mat_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

gx_1 = fx(y/c1,a,b);
gx_2 = fx(y/c2,a,b);

res = (1/(c1*c2))*conv(gx_1,gx_2,'same')*dy;
end

function res = mat_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);

hx_1 = mat_conv1(y/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
hx_2 = mat_conv1(y/d2,c1,c2,a,b);

res = (1/(d1*d2))*conv(hx_1,hx_2,'same')*dy;
end


function res = cont_conv1(y,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = 0:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    gx_1 = fx(xx/c1,a,b);
    gx_2 = fx((y(i)-xx)/c2,a,b);
    yy = gx_1.*gx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(c1*c2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end

function res = cont_conv2(y,d1,d2,c1,c2,a,b)
dy = y(2)-y(1);
xx = 0:0.01:2;

for i=1:length(y)

    hx_1 = cont_conv1(xx/d1,c1,c2,a,b);
    hx_2 = cont_conv1((y(i)-xx)/d2,c1,c2,a,b);
    yy = hx_1.*hx_2;
    yy = trapz(xx,yy);
    yy = (1/(d1*d2))*yy;
    res(i) = yy;

end
end
```

The result is given below.

[image]

As you can see the results are completely different. What am I doing wrong? How can I get rid of this discrepancy and use `conv()` to convolve the two functions in the positive domain?

Comment: Interesting question, but I think you'll find a more suitable audience at dsp.stackexchange.com or maybe math.se or stats.se.

Comment: Thanks for your advice. I don't have any authority to migrate the question. What can I do? Should I post the exact same thing there?

Comment: I've flagged it to be migrated to stats.se. I guess that if 2 more people mark it, it will be migrated automatically. Aside from that, I don't see any problem with just copying the question to another SE site.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Calculation of Convolution Integral Over a Positive Domain in MATLAB](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68066961/calculation-of-convolution-integral-over-a-positive-domain-in-matlab)